# How can I configure an rclone remote for a google drive using the app password for authentication rather than OAuth2

Tags: google-drive-api, rclone

I have an rclone remote that authenticates using OAuth2, as a backup I'd like another one that doens't rely on OAuth2 but uses the google app password.

rclone --version
rclone v1.66.0

- os/version: ubuntu 23.10 (64 bit)
- os/kernel: 6.5.0-15-generic (x86_64)
- os/type: linux
- os/arch: amd64
- go/version: go1.22.1
- go/linking: static
- go/tags: none

When I've tried to configure it, it gets stuck on the OAuth2 credentials part and won't let me around it.